# How to use customAnimation

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I've been searching all around the internet and every time I came up with the same result , I want to set a custom Animation to my Fragments , check the following code out :
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right);
    SpeedMatchFragment speedMatchFragment = new SpeedMatchFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,speedMatchFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but here **fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right);**
I'm getting **cannot resolve** error ! notice that I've already made the anim folder the xml ... and all stuff need to be done !
here is the xml code :

```
<set>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding you have to set the enter and exit animation, then the error will go like magic....

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
        SpeedMatchFragment speedMatchFragment = new SpeedMatchFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,speedMatchFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: that's not the solution I'm afraid .